# Why broadcastReceriver registered through LocalBroadcastManager works well but registerReceiver() not work?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to develop an Android app to receive data from smart insoles through broadcast receiver. I define the broadcast receiver inside the activity. I'm be able to receive the data from onReceive() when I use the **LocalBroadcastManager** to register the broadcastReceiver. However, I cannot receive any data if I use **registerReceiver()** to register the broadcastReceiver.

I want to use the **registerReceiver()** to register the broadcastReceiver since I plan to use handlerThread to let the broadcastReceiver run on a separate thread.

My code are as follows:

````
public class MoticonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private boolean mBound = false;
    private boolean standalone = true;
    boolean BLE_status = false;
    boolean isScanning = false;
    private int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private int sensorCount = 0;
    private int sensorConnect = 0;
    private int leftZeroSuccess = 0;
    private int rightZeroSuccess = 0;
    private boolean startWrite = false;
    private BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner;
    private List<String> insoleAddressesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Service.InsoleDevice> InsoleDeviceList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> InsoleAddressList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Integer> insoleSerialNumbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 0));
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 2;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION = 3;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BLUETOOTH = 4;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CONNECT = 5;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SCAN = 6;
    private BufferedWriter file;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Insole3Service.Insole3Binder mInsole3Service;
    private TextView Moticon_filenameDisplay;
    private TextView Moticon_logDisplay;

//    BroadcastReceiver br = createServiceMsgReceiver();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_moticon);
        initiatePermission();
        bindService(this, standalone);
//        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(Insole3Service.BROADCAST_SERVICE_MSG));
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Insole3Service.BROADCAST_SERVICE_MSG));
        Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Moticon_filenameDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Moticonfilename);
        Moticon_logDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Moticonlog);

        Toolbar toolbar2 = findViewById(R.id.toolbar2);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar2);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Moticon");



        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "start!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startRecoding();
                isScanning = true;
                scanAndConnection();
            }
        });

        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "stop!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                stopRecording();
                isScanning = false;

                Service.StopService stopServiceMessage = Service.StopService.newBuilder().build();
                Service.DisconnectInsoles disconnectInsolesMessage = Service.DisconnectInsoles.newBuilder().build();
                Service.MoticonMessage stopMoticonMessage = Service.MoticonMessage.newBuilder()
                        .setStopService(stopServiceMessage)
                        .setDisconnectInsoles(disconnectInsolesMessage)
                        .build();
                sendProtoToService(stopMoticonMessage.toByteArray());
                Log.i("Info","disconnecting...");
            }
        });


    }

    private void initiatePermission(){

        //PowerManagement permission
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            String packageName = getPackageName();
            if (!powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName)) {
                Log.i("Info","disable battery optimization...");

                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        //BLE permission
        boolean bluetoothAvailable = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);
        if (!bluetoothAvailable) {
            Log.i("Bluetooth", "Bluetooth is not supported");
        }
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        bluetoothLeScanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        if (bluetoothAdapter != null && !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Log.i("Info","Bluetooth not enabled");
            // Device doesn't support Bluetooth
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BLUETOOTH);
                Log.i("Info", "Bluetooth permission deny...");
                return;
            } else {
                Log.i("info", "BLUETOOTH permission granted");
            }
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CONNECT);
            Log.i("Info", "Connection permission deny...");
            return;
        } else {
            Log.i("info", "Connection permission granted");
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SCAN);
            Log.i("Info", "Bluetooth SCAN permission deny...");
            return;
        } else {
            Log.i("info", "BLUETOOTH SCAN permission granted");
        }
        //LocationPermission
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First enable FINE LOCATION ACCESS in settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
            return;
        } else {
            Log.i("Info", "Fine permission granted");
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First enable COARSE LOCATION ACCESS in settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
            return;
        } else {
            Log.i("Info", "Coarse permission granted");
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First enable BACKGROUND LOCATION ACCESS in settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
            return;
        } else {
            Log.i("Info", "Background permission granted");
        }

    }

    private void scanAndConnection() {
            Service.StartInsoleScan startInsoleScanMessage = Service.StartInsoleScan.newBuilder().build();
            Service.MoticonMessage moticonMessage1 = Service.MoticonMessage.newBuilder()
                    .setStartInsoleScan(startInsoleScanMessage)
                    .build();
            sendProtoToService(moticonMessage1.toByteArray());

            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                // Process the message

            while(InsoleDeviceList.size()<2){
                ;
            }

            Service.StopInsoleScan stopInsoleScanMessage = Service.StopInsoleScan.newBuilder().build();
            Service.MoticonMessage moticonMessage4 = Service.MoticonMessage.newBuilder()
                    .setStopInsoleScan(stopInsoleScanMessage)
                    .build();
            sendProtoToService(moticonMessage4.toByteArray());

            Log.i("Info","InsoleDeviceList:  " + InsoleDeviceList);

                Service.ConnectInsoles connectInsolesMessage1 = Service.ConnectInsoles.newBuilder()
                        .addAllInsoles(InsoleDeviceList)
                        .build();
                Service.MoticonMessage moticonMessage3 = Service.MoticonMessage.newBuilder()
                        .setConnectInsoles(connectInsolesMessage1)
                        .build();
                sendProtoToService(moticonMessage3.toByteArray());

                while (sensorCount < 1) {
                        ;
                }
                try {
                    Thread. sleep(1000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                initiateSensor(insoleSerialNumbers);

                return 0;
            });


    }

    private void initiateSensor(List<Integer> SerialNumberList){
        Log.i("Info","initating sensors...");

        //initiate sensors
        Common.ServiceConfig initServiceCfg = Common.ServiceConfig.newBuilder()
                .setServiceStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setServiceId(Common.ServiceId.newBuilder().setLeftSerialNumber(SerialNumberList.get(0)).setRightSerialNumber(SerialNumberList.get(1)).build())
                .setServiceType(Common.ServiceType.LIVE)
                .setRate(100)
                .addEnabledPressure(true)
                .addEnabledPressure(true)
                .addEnabledPressure(true)
                .addEnabledPressure(true)
                .addEnabledPressure(true)
                .addEnabledPressure(true)
                .addEnabledPressure(true)
                .addEnabledPressure(true)
                .addEnabledPressure(true)
                .addEnabledPressure(true)
                .addEnabledPressure(true)
                .addEnabledPressure(true)
                .addEnabledPressure(true)
                .addEnabledPressure(true)
                .addEnabledPressure(true)
                .addEnabledPressure(true)
                .addEnabledAcceleration(true)
                .addEnabledAcceleration(true)
                .addEnabledAcceleration(true)
                .setAccGRange(Common.ServiceConfig.AccGRange.ACC_16_G)
                .setAccOdr(Common.ServiceConfig.AccOdr.ACC_208_ODR)
                .addEnabledAngular(true)
                .addEnabledAngular(true)
                .addEnabledAngular(true)
                .setAngDpsRange(Common.ServiceConfig.AngDpsRange.ANG_2000_DPS)
                .setAngOdr(Common.ServiceConfig.AngOdr.ANG_208_ODR)
                .setEnabledTemperature(true)
                .setEnabledTotalForce(true)
                .setActivityProfile(Common.ServiceConfig.ActivityProfile.ACTIVITY_PROFILE_CONTINUOUS)
                .setIsPreview(false)
                .build();

        Common.MeasurementInfo measurementInfo = Common.MeasurementInfo.newBuilder()
                .setName("")
                .setComment("")
                .build();
        Common.ServiceEndpoint endpointCfg = Common.ServiceEndpoint.newBuilder()
                .setEndpointType(Common.ServiceEndpoint.EndpointType.APP)
                .build();
        Common.Zeroing leftZeroingCfg = Common.Zeroing.newBuilder()
                .setSource(Common.ZeroingSource.KEEP)
                .setMode(Common.ZeroingMode.AUTO)
                .setSide(Common.Side.LEFT)
                .build();

        Common.Zeroing rightZeroingCfg = Common.Zeroing.newBuilder()
                .setSource(Common.ZeroingSource.KEEP)
                .setMode(Common.ZeroingMode.AUTO)
                .setSide(Common.Side.RIGHT)
                .build();

        // set sensor information
        Service.StartService startServiceMessage = Service.StartService.newBuilder()
                .setServiceConfig(initServiceCfg)
                .setMeasurementInfo(measurementInfo)
                .setServiceEndpoint(endpointCfg)
                .build();

        Service.MoticonMessage leftZeroingMessage = Service.MoticonMessage.newBuilder()
                .setZeroing(leftZeroingCfg)
                .build();
        sendProtoToService(leftZeroingMessage.toByteArray());

        Service.MoticonMessage rightZeroingMessage = Service.MoticonMessage.newBuilder()
                .setZeroing(rightZeroingCfg)
                .build();
        sendProtoToService(rightZeroingMessage.toByteArray());

        Service.MoticonMessage moticonMessage5 = Service.MoticonMessage.newBuilder()
                .setStartService(startServiceMessage)
                .build();
        sendProtoToService(moticonMessage5.toByteArray());
        Log.i("Info: ", "startServiceMessage: " + moticonMessage5);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                BLE_status = true;
                Log.i("BLE_status: ", "enabled");
                // Bluetooth is now enabled
            } else {
                // User declined to enable Bluetooth
                BLE_status = false;
                Log.i("BLE_status: ", "disabled");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
//        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(br);
        try {
            if(broadcastReceiver != null){
                unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
                Log.i("Info","UnregisterReceiver....");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        unbindService();
    }

    private void startRecoding() {
        // Prepare data storage
        File directory = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMddyyyyHHmm");
        Date currentdate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String name = "AllData_" + sdf.format(currentdate) + ".csv";
        File filename = new File(directory, name);
        try {
            file = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Moticon_filenameDisplay.setText(name);
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        Moticon_filenameDisplay.setText("");
    }

    private boolean bindService(Context context, boolean standalone) {
        Intent mIntentInsole3 = new Intent(this, Insole3Service.class);
        mIntentInsole3.putExtra("standalone", standalone);

        Log.i(TAG, "Start the service");
        try {
            if (mBound) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Service is already bound. Do not bind again");
            } else {
                context.startService(mIntentInsole3);
                Log.i(TAG, "Bind to the service");
                context.bindService(mIntentInsole3, mServiceConnection, 0);
                mBound = true;
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException illegalStateException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't bind service as it seems to be in the background: " +
                    illegalStateException);
        }
        return mBound;
    }

    private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Log.i("Info", "onServiceConnected");
            Log.i("Info","Service type: " + service.getClass().getName());
            mInsole3Service = (Insole3Service.Insole3Binder) service;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Log.i("Info", "onServiceDisconnected");
            mInsole3Service = null;
        }
    };

    private void unbindService() {
        Log.i("Info", "Unbind from the service ");
        mBound = false;
        try {
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
            Log.e("Info", "Can't unbind service as it seems not bound: " +
                    illegalArgumentException);
        }
    }

    private void sendProtoToService(byte[] message) {
        try{
            Intent broadcast = new Intent(Insole3Service.BROADCAST_CONTROLLER_MSG);
            broadcast.putExtra(Insole3Service.EXTRA_PROTO_MSG, message);
//            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(broadcast);
            sendBroadcast(broadcast);
            Log.i("Info","send Proto: " + message);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("sendProtoToService","Failed to send proto message",e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i("Info", "FINE permission granted");
                // Permission was granted; you can now use location services
            } else {
                // Permission was denied; handle it accordingly
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FINE Location permission denied. You may not be able to use location-related features.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i("Info", "COARSE permission granted");
                // Permission was granted; you can now use location services
            } else {
                // Permission was denied; handle it accordingly
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "COARSE Location permission denied. You may not be able to use location-related features.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i("Info", "BACKGROUND permission granted");
                // Permission was granted; you can now use location services
            } else {
                // Permission was denied; handle it accordingly
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BACKGROUND Location permission denied. You may not be able to use location-related features.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_BLUETOOTH) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i("Info", "Bluetooth permission granted");
                // Permission was granted; you can now use location services
            } else {
                // Permission was denied; handle it accordingly
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth permission denied. You may not be able to use bluetooth-related features.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CONNECT) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i("Info", "Connection permission granted");
                // Permission was granted; you can now use location services
            } else {
                // Permission was denied; handle it accordingly
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth connection denied. You may not be able to use connection-related features.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SCAN) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i("Info", "Connection permission granted");
                // Permission was granted; you can now use location services
            } else {
                // Permission was denied; handle it accordingly
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth connection denied. You may not be able to use connection-related features.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }


    }
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
//    public BroadcastReceiver createServiceMsgReceiver(){
//        return new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.i("Info","broadcast receiver start...");
                String action = intent.getAction();
                Log.i("Info","Action: " + action);
                byte[] protoMsg = intent.getByteArrayExtra(Insole3Service.EXTRA_PROTO_MSG);
                try {Service.MoticonMessage moticonMessage = Service.MoticonMessage.parseFrom(protoMsg);
//                    Log.i("Info","MoticonMessage: " + moticonMessage);
                    // Continue processing the received message
                    switch(moticonMessage.getMsgCase()){
                        case ZEROING_CONF:
                            Log.i("Info","zeroing: "+ moticonMessage.getZeroingConf().getSide() + " "+ moticonMessage.getZeroingConf().getError());
                            if (moticonMessage.getZeroingConf().getError().getErrorCode() == Common.ErrorCode.SUCCESS) {
                                if (moticonMessage.getZeroingConf().getSide() == Common.Side.LEFT) {
                                    leftZeroSuccess = 1;
                                } else {
                                    rightZeroSuccess = 1;
                                }
                            }

                            if (leftZeroSuccess+rightZeroSuccess==2){
                                startWrite = true;
                            }
                            break;

                        case TIMESTAMP_CONF:
                            Log.i("Info","TIMESTAMP!!");
                            Long Tx = moticonMessage.getTimestampConf().getTimeTx();
                            Long Rx = moticonMessage.getTimestampConf().getTimeRx();
                            Log.i("Info","Tx: " + Tx + " " + "Rx: "+ Rx);
                            break;
                        case DATA_MESSAGE:
                            // HANDLE PROTO MESSAGES HERE:
                            if (startWrite){
                                Long sensorTime = moticonMessage.getDataMessage().getTime();
                                String sensorSide = moticonMessage.getDataMessage().getSide().name();
//                                int sensorSide = moticonMessage.getDataMessage().getSide().getNumber();
                                List<Float> acc = moticonMessage.getDataMessage().getAccelerationList();
                                List<Float> gyro = moticonMessage.getDataMessage().getAngularList();
                                List<Integer> pressure = moticonMessage.getDataMessage().getPressureList();
                                long phoneTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                write(phoneTime,sensorTime, sensorSide, acc, gyro, pressure);
                            }
                            break;

                        case INSOLE_ADVERTISEMENT:
                            Log.i("Info","Received advertisement data");
                            Log.i("Info","device found: "+ InsoleDeviceList.size());
                            Service.InsoleDevice insoleDevice = moticonMessage.getInsoleAdvertisement().getInsole();
                            String insoleAddress = insoleDevice.getDeviceAddress();
                            Common.Side insoleSide = insoleDevice.getSide();
                            int batteryLevel = moticonMessage.getInsoleAdvertisement().getBatteryLevel();
                            int insoleSize = insoleDevice.getSize();
                            if (InsoleDeviceList.size()<2){
                                if (!InsoleAddressList.contains(insoleAddress)){
                                    InsoleAddressList.add(insoleAddress);
                                    InsoleDeviceList.add(insoleDevice);
                                    if (insoleDevice.getSide().name().equals("LEFT")){
                                        insoleSerialNumbers.set(0,insoleDevice.getSerialNumber());
                                        Log.i("Info","Left found");}
                                    else{
                                        insoleSerialNumbers.set(1,insoleDevice.getSerialNumber());
                                        Log.i("Info","Right found");}
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case INSOLE_CONNECTION_STATUS:
                             Service.InsoleConnectionStatus.Status sensorConnect = moticonMessage.getInsoleConnectionStatus().getStatus();
                             if (sensorConnect == Service.InsoleConnectionStatus.Status.READY){
                                 sensorCount += 1;
                             }
                             Log.i("Info","connectedSensorCount: "+ sensorConnect + " " + sensorCount);
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
                    // Handle the exception
                    Log.i("Info","Invalid Protocol Buffer");
                }
            }
        };
//    }


    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void write(long phoneTime, long sensorTime, String sideSide, List<Float> acc, List<Float> gyro, List<Integer> pressure) {
        if (file == null) {
            return;
        }

        String line;
        String data = "";
        if (acc != null) {
            for (Float value : acc) {
                data += ", " + value;
            }
        }

        if (gyro != null) {
            for (Float value : gyro) {
                data += ", " + value;
            }
        }

        if (pressure != null) {
            for (Integer value : pressure) {
                data += ", " + value;
            }
        }
        line = phoneTime + "," + sensorTime + ", " + sideSide + data + "\n";

        try {
            file.write(line);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Moticon_logDisplay.setText(line);
    }


} ```
````

Comment: "I'm be able to receive the data from onReceive() when I use the LocalBroadcastManager to register the broadcastReceiver." -- `LocalBroadcastManager` has been deprecated for years. "I cannot receive any data if I use registerReceiver() to register the broadcastReceiver." -- broadcasting implicit `Intents` has been banned for years. If you have one process, use something modern and supported for your inter-thread communication. Since you are using Java, RxJava might be a suitable choice.